# Difference in rendering result vs viewport in v.2.8.0

Tags: rendering

I have a problem with final rendering, which is different from what I can see in the viewport. Previous replies to similar topics don't help, nothing changes. It shows some addidional noise and looks totally awful, I have checked the color management settings and everything seems to be ok, but I'm completely new to blender so I may have sth checked or unchecked, no idea. I'm using v. 2.8.0. No idea whatsoever where the problem may be.. Thanks!

[image]

[render problem](https://ibb.co/dfjhXbZ)

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome! What is the viewport image? What is the rendering? Also which posts do you have read already? Could you please link them? I guess there is overlapping geometry but can't be sure (check your outliner). Consider sharing a minimal example preferably using: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi, the first one is viewport image and the one at the bottom is rendered. Here's the file. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=jNAXKq4r" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/jNAXKq4r/), does it work? thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is overlapping geometry:

[image]

This button does not mean the mesh won't be rendered:

[image]

To disable things to be rendered, you need to use *"disable in renders"* buttons:

[image]

Comment: heeey! Thanks! Lovely! <3

Comment: Hi @kasia. Please consider to accept the answer. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour